# Generate Excel file thumbnail preview in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I have a project handling a library of excel files. To make it easilier for the users to visually scan them, I would like to generate preview thumbnail images of their content. Google drive does this (screenshot below) but I have no idea how.

[image]

Any ideas/suggestions on how this could be done (without using the drive API) ?

Comment: What's this picture for, ants? :)

Comment: Just make a general icon / image. The image will always be to small to visually interpret the data.

Comment: @artm Accessibility features for ants is definitely a strong interest of mine.

Comment: Even when I use "view image" it's tiny man, can't see what's what, try a larger image so we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: What he is talking about is perfectly straightforward: He wants to generate small thumbnail previews of XLS documents like Google Drive does. The thumbnails are not supposed to be readable, they're supposed to give you a quick overview of which document is which.

Comment: @ThomasEschemann - have you had any luck with a solution? I'd love to know what you've discovered since asking the question originally.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is what you need

http://github.com/lonekorean/mini-preview

DEMO

```js
/*
 * MiniPreview v0.9
 *
 * @author  Will Boyd
 * @github  http://github.com/lonekorean/mini-preview
 */

(function($) {
    var PREFIX = 'mini-preview';
    
    // implemented as a jQuery plugin
    $.fn.miniPreview = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var miniPreview = $this.data(PREFIX);
            if (miniPreview) {
                miniPreview.destroy();
            }

            miniPreview = new MiniPreview($this, options);
            miniPreview.generate();
            $this.data(PREFIX, miniPreview);
        });
    };
    
    var MiniPreview = function($el, options) {
        this.$el = $el;
        this.$el.addClass(PREFIX + '-anchor');
        this.options = $.extend({}, this.defaultOptions, options);
        this.counter = MiniPreview.prototype.sharedCounter++;
    };
    
    MiniPreview.prototype = {
        sharedCounter: 0,
        
        defaultOptions: {
            width: 256,
            height: 144,
            scale: .25,
            prefetch: 'pageload'
        },
                
        generate: function() {
            this.createElements();
            this.setPrefetch();
        },

        createElements: function() {
            var $wrapper = $('<div>', { class: PREFIX + '-wrapper' });
            var $loading = $('<div>', { class: PREFIX + '-loading' });
            var $frame = $('<iframe>', { class: PREFIX + '-frame' });
            var $cover = $('<div>', { class: PREFIX + '-cover' });
            $wrapper.appendTo(this.$el).append($loading, $frame, $cover);
            
            // sizing
            $wrapper.css({
                width: this.options.width + 'px',
                height: this.options.height + 'px'
            });
            
            // scaling
            var inversePercent = 100 / this.options.scale;
            $frame.css({
                width: inversePercent + '%',
                height: inversePercent + '%',
                transform: 'scale(' + this.options.scale + ')'
            });

            // positioning
            var fontSize = parseInt(this.$el.css('font-size').replace('px', ''), 10)
            var top = (this.$el.height() + fontSize) / 2;
            var left = (this.$el.width() - $wrapper.outerWidth()) / 2;
            $wrapper.css({
                top: top + 'px',
                left: left + 'px'
            });
        },
        
        setPrefetch: function() {
            switch (this.options.prefetch) {
                case 'pageload':
                    this.loadPreview();
                    break;
                case 'parenthover':
                    this.$el.parent().one(this.getNamespacedEvent('mouseenter'),
                        this.loadPreview.bind(this));
                    break;
                case 'none':
                    this.$el.one(this.getNamespacedEvent('mouseenter'),
                        this.loadPreview.bind(this));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw 'Prefetch setting not recognized: ' + this.options.prefetch;
                    break;
            }
        },
        
        loadPreview: function() {
            this.$el.find('.' + PREFIX + '-frame')
                .attr('src', this.$el.attr('href'))
                .on('load', function() {
                    // some sites don't set their background color
                    $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');
                });
        },
        
        getNamespacedEvent: function(event) {
            return event + '.' + PREFIX + '_' + this.counter;
        },

        destroy: function() {
            this.$el.removeClass(PREFIX + '-anchor');
            this.$el.parent().off(this.getNamespacedEvent('mouseenter'));
            this.$el.off(this.getNamespacedEvent('mouseenter'));
            this.$el.find('.' + PREFIX + '-wrapper').remove();
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.mini-preview-anchor {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.mini-preview-wrapper {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: -4px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    transition: z-index steps(1) .3s, opacity .3s, margin-top .3s;
}

.mini-preview-anchor:hover .mini-preview-wrapper {
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 6px;
    transition: opacity .3s, margin-top .3s;
}

.mini-preview-loading, .mini-preview-cover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;    
}

.mini-preview-loading {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f5ead4;
    background-color: #59513f;
}

.mini-preview-loading::before {
    content: 'Loading...';
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.mini-preview-cover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /* IE fix */
}

.mini-preview-frame {
    border: none;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>MiniPreview Demo</title>

        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0 10% 40px;
                font-size: 2rem;
                line-height: 1.5;
                font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
                text-align: justify;
                color: #59513f;
                background-color: #f5ead4;
            }

            a {
                color: #537f7c;
            }

            .break {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- MiniPreview stuff here -->
        <link href="./jquery.minipreview.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="./jquery.minipreview.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#p1 a').miniPreview({ prefetch: 'pageload' });
                $('#p2 a').miniPreview({ prefetch: 'parenthover' });
                $('#p3 a').miniPreview({ prefetch: 'none' });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="p1">
            This demo shows how to add live mini-previews to links on hover. Check out these links to <a href="http://www.sitepoint.com/">SitePoint</a> and <a href="http://alistapart.com/">A List Apart</a>. Hover over them to see a small preview of what they point to.
        </p>
        <p class="break">&bull; &bull; &bull;</p>
        <p id="p2">
            Those previews were fetched as soon as this page loaded. This is great for having the previews ready ahead of time, but can eat up extra bandwidth. As an alternative, check out these links to <a href="http://abduzeedo.com/">Abduzeedo</a> and <a href="http://www.smashingmagazine.com/">Smashing Magazine</a>. These previews aren't fetched until you hover over this paragraph.
        </p>
        <p class="break">&bull; &bull; &bull;</p>
        <p id="p3">
            Finally, check out these links to <a href="http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/">Daniel's blog</a>, <a href="http://jonibologna.com/">Joni's blog</a>, and <a href="http://codersblock.com/blog/">my blog</a>. These previews are only fetched when needed. This saves the most bandwidth, but there will be a delay before the previews can be shown.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

ORIGINAL SOURCE:

http://codepen.io/kanakiyajay/pen/NqgZjo

Answer (score -1):

I just use a library to generate a PNG preview of the excel file and show it.

I use [Free Spire.XLS for .NET](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-xls-component.html) because I'm in the .net world, but you can look at [Wijmo Workbook Viewer](https://www.grapecity.com/wijmo/demos/Excel/WorkbookViewer/purejs) for your Node.js needs.